# How to individually render Http-related Exceptions then render all other exceptions in a common place in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I am implementing exceptions in Laravel. I'm grateful that Laravel handles all its exceptions in one place!

Laravel also allows us to create landing pages for some common errors depending on status e.g. to catch 404, create `404.blade.php` on `views/errors`. Now, I want to catch a number of common http-related errors e.g. 404, 401, 403 and 405 so that they automatically redirect to their named views, then for all other errors, I want to redirect them to a common error landing page.

The question is: how do I let Laravel know that it should auto-handle the "named" errors first before it calls the other non-http-related ones?

This is what I have done so far, but the exceptions do not seem to be instances of `HttpException`. How else should I catch them?

```
// app/Exceptions/Handler.php
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    // I want these ones to be picked and routed to the relevant page (401, 403, 404, 405)
    if($e instanceof HttpException && $e->getStatusCode()== 404)
    {
        return response()->view('errors.404');
    }
    elseif($e instanceof HttpException && $e->getStatusCode()== 405)
    {
        return response()->view('errors.405');
    }
    elseif($e instanceof HttpException && $e->getStatusCode()== 401)
    {
        return $this->unauthenticated($request,$e);
    }
    elseif($e instanceof HttpException && $e->getStatusCode()== 403)
    {
        return response()->view('errors.403');
    }
     elseif($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException)
    {
        return response()->view('error.model-not-found');
    }

    // // then the rest can go to a common page

     return response()->view('errors.caught-errors', [
        'error' => 'Error encountered.',
        'description' => 'Brief public-friendly description.'
    ]);
    // Laravel default renderer
    //return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: When in doubt, start logging and go from there. Before your if statements, try `Log::info(get_class($e));` Then you can figure out which exceptions are being passed in and decide where you want to route them.

Comment: Good suggestion there. I have triggered `401` like this `abort(401)`, and on logging, its class is `HttpException`, yet the `$e instanceof HtttpException` evaluates to false. What could be the issue?